# skew div with click ondivision

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

i have a div that it has image content i wanna skew it when user click on div or image with delay .i use follow code but it dose not work. what is solution ?
thanks

```
  $(function () {
        $('#hd').bind('mousedown', function () {
            var $elem = $(this);

              $elem.animate({  " -webkit-transform": "skewX(40deg)" }, 250)
        })
    })
```

it does not work too

```
   $(function () {
        $('#hd').bind('mousedown', function () {
            var $elem = $(this);
            $elem.css({ " -webkit-transform": "skewX(40deg)"

            })

        })
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra whitespace:

```
$elem.css({"-webkit-transform": "skewX(40deg)" });
```

The space before `-webkit-transform` is what is causing it not to work.

Comment: thanks for reply .ok u are right but how can i do it with delay css function work properly with your guide but animate dose not work still.how can edit it or replace with other function?

Comment: from what I'm able to find, you can't use animate directly with some of those special styles that have non-numeric values.

Comment: are there alternative for animate for this task?

Comment: yes, if you search for "animate webkit transform" on this site you will find several questions with ways of doing it.